# user data update if user login with in 24 hours range in magento

Tags: php, magento

i would like to update points of my customer who logged in every 24 hours range. Means if the user visit daily the user will get 50 points. For example : user last visited at : now then tomorrow if the user visit again he will get point.

Well, i guess i can make it in two ways.
I have a time colum in my points table like the last time the points update. So, i have to set minimum 24 hours to update points set to +50 from the time colum from points talbe.

Or, else i can do it from session right.

I guess from time table it will be more easier for me.

So anyone can give me a code or example code to code it. Well i guess i will able to make it but i am kind of confused so can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Preaumbule:

*If I don't mistake every request is logged in database. In CE module Mage_Log is responsible for this. Moreover there is such table as log_customer. So you can catch the customer logging in.*

What you have for now? Do you have any module or something? I would suggest you to catch customer logging in event or rewrite some existing class and write down to your database table all info you need.

Comment: well, i just made it more simple to work fast. Like i have a points table where i have time column when user register current time will be input there. Now after that when the user is back it will check either the time is less or more then 24 hours. Well if yes then it will update 50 points if no then the query will not run. Now i need a code example for time thing. I mean my data column name is time where i am getting the time value. So i want to get a query will happen if the time data from table is more then 24 hours from now.